# "Set" find the suffix string

Tags: c++

I would like to know if it is possible to use the `std::set::find()` function to search for the suffix "COMP" in the `std::set<std::string>`.

```
set<string> str;
str.insert("33333COMP");

set<string>::const_iterator setIter;
setIter = str.find("COMP");
if (setIter != str.end())
{
    cout << "FOUND" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Not Found!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Well.. does it work?

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: You can use [this code](http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-suffix-tree/) - it is the implementation of a suffix tree, which can help you find what you're looking for.

Comment: @Nandu `std::string::find` is likely more performant and more readable than a regex ever will be.

Comment: you have facts to back up that? If its a personal preference, I'd understand. Regex's are more powerful and robust than string::find

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it from Set. Maybe you can use some other data structures, like Trie Tree.